# dealing with ljpeg (lossless jpeg) using matlab

Tags: matlab, jpeg, lossless-compression

I am dealing now with DDSM database (Digital Database for Screening Mammography) .. its disadvantage is its extension. It is extension is ljpeg (lossless jpeg) which it is very poorly supported extension. I want to read them using matlab or converting them to any other type which is widely supported. thank

Comment: According to [the documentation](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/ref/imread.html), Matlab supports JPEGs with lossless compression.

Answer (score 6):

I know there is a working version of DDSM's jpeg program for linux at http://www.cs.unibo.it/~roffilli/sw.html
I compiled and tested it. I used the MATLAB code as described here to view the images.
It displays correctly only for some scanners.
As described in the paper http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.111.3846
When properly compiled, the DDSM software outputs the image data as a stream of raw bytes; one then has to normalise these according to the model of digitiser used to image the original films and then create an image file that is readable by one’s image analysis software environment.

****EDIT:*** *
I found a **complete** solution that downloads, normalizes (based on the scanner) and converts the DDSM image to PNG format. Dr. Chris Rose wrote that program, please download it on his website

http://microserf.org.uk/academic/Software.html