# Dealing with ljpeg in Python

Tags: python, image, jpeg, lossless-compression

I'm having a quite huge but stupid problem. I couldn't find any way to open an ljpeg (lossless jpeg) file with python, or in any other way. Isn't there any library or something? Any other programming language would be okay, any other way at all would be okay. I just need to open that file somehow.

Answer (score 0):

In another post, someone recommended: http://ebiznisz.hu/python-jpegtran/

PostUrl:https://stackoverflow.com/a/15900716/2620328

Answer (score 0):

You can also use another answer recommended in this [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9053024/dealing-with-ljpeg-lossless-jpeg-using-matlab)

Is it at all possible for you to convert your file to a different format?

You can convert the format into a more traditional format using [a patch](http://www.imagemagick.org/pipermail/magick-users/2003-May/009042.html) to the libjpeg library and then use any any language / library such as Python's [PIL](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/) or MATLAB's imread function.